# .NET Hashtable vs Dictionary - Can the Dictionary be as fast?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, collections, hashtable

I am trying to figure out when and why to use a `Dictionary` or a `Hashtable`.  I have done a bit of a search on here and have found people talking about the generic advantages of the `Dictionary` which I totally agree with, which leads the boxing and unboxing advantage for a slight performance gain.

But I have also read the `Dictionary` will not always return the objects in the order they are inserted, thing it is sorted.  Where as a `Hashtable` will.  As I understand it this leads to the `Hashtable` being far faster for some situations.

My question is really, what might those situations be?  Am I just wrong in my assumptions above?  What situations might you use to choose one above the other, (yes the last one is a bit ambiguous).

Comment: I wan't to upvote this, but your karma is 7,777 and I don't want to be the guy that messes that up for you.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `System.Collections.Hashtable` classes both maintain a hash table data structure internally. **None of them guarantee preserving the order of items.**

Leaving boxing/unboxing issues aside, most of the time, they should have very similar performance.

The primary structural difference between them is that `Dictionary` relies on *chaining* (maintaining a list of items for each hash table bucket) to resolve collisions whereas `Hashtable` uses *rehashing* for collision resolution (when a collision occurs, tries another hash function to map the key to a bucket).

There is little benefit to use `Hashtable` class if you are targeting for .NET Framework 2.0+. It's effectively rendered obsolete by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @Jon- The chaining and rehashing is discussed in depth here- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you both.  Just found that page as Richard posted it... Was going to ask about Chaining but the MSDN site is actually helpful!

Comment: @Mehrdad - What's not clear to me about how collisions are resolved is this:if multiple keys could result in the same hash, then how do you ensure you're getting the right value on lookups, ie how does the function know which element to return? In  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28VS.80%29.aspx it says,"Rather than reprobing in the event of a collision, as is done with the Hashtable class, the Dictionary simply chains any collisions onto the bucket's list." Does this mean that when using Dictionary, collisions are not something the developer has to worry about?

Comment: @Howiecamp: This is not really much different from `Hashtable`. Hash tables store 3 pieces of information in an entry: key hash, key itself, and the value. For items with equal hash, it'll have to traverse the list to find the item with equal key and return its value. This is pretty much true for `Hashtable` too. As a developer using a `Dictionary` normally, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Just to be clear, both the Hashtable and Dictionary objects store the key itself, and both also hide collisions from the developer?

Comment: to add to this, hash tables are thread safe.  not all operations with a dictionary are thread safe

Comment: *"None of them guarantee preserving the order of items."` - There is no such thing as an order with hash tables in general. They don't store data index based but based on a key mapping. When you say *"not guaranteed"* it implies that there actually is an order and with some luck the order is the original order in which elements were added.

Answer (score 131):

I guess it doesn't mean anything to you now. But just for reference for people stopping by

[Performance Test - SortedList vs. SortedDictionary vs. Dictionary vs. Hashtable](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/)

**Memory allocation:**

[image: Memory usage performance test]

**Time used for inserting:**

[image: Time used for inserting]

**Time for searching an item:**

[image: Time for searching an item]

Comment: @JohnHenckel no, sorted list has slower lookup. Bigger performance coefficient means better performance and better memory usage. So, sorted list has the best memory usage according to the charts but it sucks in other areas such as inserting and lookup.

Comment: Hi all, Sorry to ask a basic question. But, if "bigger performance coefficient" means better performance, then from the charts, it looks like Hashtable is faster than Dictionary ? If yes, then why do people say that Dictionary is faster than Hastable in practice (because Dictionary does not use boxing/unboxing) ?

Comment: I am confused by the meaning of the units in this graph. If the Y-axis is "time", a higher value should be "more time", but my own test shows a SortedDictionary is much slower than Dictionary. So, perhaps add a message "Higher is faster"

Answer (score 38):

### Differences between Hashtable and Dictionary

Dictionary:

- Dictionary returns error if we try to find a key which does not exist.
- **Dictionary faster than a Hashtable because there is no boxing and unboxing.**
- Dictionary is a generic type which means we can use it with any data type.

Hashtable:

- Hashtable returns null if we try to find a key which does not exist.
- **Hashtable slower than dictionary because it requires boxing and unboxing.**
- Hashtable is not a generic type,

Comment: That's the answer

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with the given answer that seems to indicate hashtables have better performance in most cases?

Answer (score 25):

Another important difference is that the Hashtable type supports lock-free multiple readers and a single writer at the same time, while Dictionary does not.

Comment: Concurrent Dictionary will support(.Net 4.0)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this answer. Looking here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx it says "To support multiple writers all operations on the Hashtable must be done through the wrapper returned by the Synchronized method, provided that there are no threads reading the Hashtable object." That seems to make the "lock-free multiple readers" feature pretty useless, so then we're back to having to lock all access to the Hashtable, just like with Dictionary.

Answer (score 18):

> MSDN Article: "The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class has the same
>   functionality as the `Hashtable` class. A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
>   of a specific type (other than `Object`) has better performance than a
>   `Hashtable` for value types because the elements of `Hashtable` are of
>   type `Object` and, therefore, boxing and unboxing typically occur if
>   storing or retrieving a value type".

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 11):

Both are effectively the same class (you can look at the disassembly).  HashTable was created first before .Net had generics.  Dictionary, however is a generic class and gives you strong typing benefits.  I would never use HashTable since Dictionary costs you nothing to use.

Answer (score 9):

Another important difference is that `Hashtable` is thread safe. `Hashtable` has built in multiple reader/single writer (MR/SW) thread safety which means `Hashtable` allows ONE writer together with multiple readers without locking. In the case of `Dictionary` there is no thread safety, if you need thread safety you must implement your own synchronization.

To elaborate further:

> `Hashtable`, provide some thread-safety through the Synchronized property, which returns a thread-safe wrapper around the collection. The wrapper works by locking the entire collection on every add or remove operation. Therefore, each thread that is attempting to access the collection must wait for its turn to take the one lock. This is not scalable and can cause significant performance degradation for large collections. Also, the design is not completely protected from race conditions.
>
> The .NET Framework 2.0 collection classes like  `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, etc do not provide any thread synchronization; user code must provide all synchronization when items are added or removed on multiple threads concurrently
> If you need type safety as well thread safety, use concurrent collections classes in the .NET Framework. Further reading here.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries have the advantage of being a generic type, which makes it type safe and a bit faster due to lack of need for boxing. The following [comparison table](https://kap-project-nsh-2504.firebaseapp.com/currtask?accessToken=jpAVSBo0TbaROkUvPZBAQUHT1Vp1&taskId=-LQamYtyUSOb0irso5G5) (constructed using the answers found in a similar SO [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable#comment296514_301384)) illustrates some of the other reasons that support dictionaries over hash tables (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

If you care about reading that will always return the objects in the order they are inserted in a Dictionary, you may have a look at

[OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) - values can be accessed via an integer index (by order in which items were added)
[SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/f7fta44c) - items are automatically sorted

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is faster than hashtable as dictionary is a generic strong type. Hashtable is slower as it takes object as data type which leads to boxing and unboxing.

Comment: http://www.phase9studios.com/post/2008/01/08/DictionaryVSHashTable.aspx  plz read the comments below the article

Comment: @Arvand Link broken - domain for sale.