# Fast find object by string property

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I've got task to fast find object by its string property.
Object:

```
  class DicDomain
  {
    public virtual string Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

For storing my object I use List[T] dictionary where T is DicDomain for now .
I've got 5-10 such lists, which contain about 500-20000 at each one.
Task is find objects by its Name.
I use next code now:

```
  List<T> entities = dictionary.FindAll(s => s.Name.Equals(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I've got some questions:

Is my search speed optimal. I think now.

1. Data structure. It List good for this task. What about hashtable,sorted...
2. Method Find. May be i should use string intern??

I haven't much exp at these tasks. Can u give me good advice for increase perfomance.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are performing this operation frequently, you can build a `Dictionary<string, List<DicDomain>>` (or `Dictionary<string, DicDomain>` if `Name` is unique) to build a reverse mapping (from a name to a bunch of `DicDomain` objects) and keep that dictionary up to date.

The task will be a simple hash table lookup after that:

```
 var list = dictionary[name];
```

Comment: Frequently 100000 times every day. Thanks for advice!!! I can't imagine such nice way. And what about Dictionary vs HashTable?

Comment: @Andrew: Short answer: `Dictionary`. Long answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast/1089142#1089142

Comment: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase and what about this. How can i implement CaseInsensetive search?

Comment: @Andrew: You can pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the `Dictionary` constructor to control the way keys are compared.