# When and where to Use Dictionary verses Hashtable?

Tags: c#

I know advantages and disadvantages of Hashtable and Dictionary.

I want to know when Hash-table is preferred over Dictionary ?

Comment: Are you sure you know advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable

Comment: yes i know basics but i don't know the scenrio in which Hash-Table is preferred over Dictionary.

Comment: See the first answer to the first question linked by @SonerGönül this is explained

Comment: When would you prefer something that's generally slower, not type safe and requires more code from you to use in any non-trivial scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashTable` is not a Generic Collection, so you can save anytype (object) types into `Hashtable` and its type is not known at compile time.

`Dictionary` is a Generic collection so you need to specify the type before saving elements into it, so it is `type safe`.

> I want to know when Hash-table is preferred over Dictionary ?

i don't think this is true because `Dictionary` is `Typesafe` and also faster because of no burden of `boxing and unboxing` of the elements as its elements type is known at compile time.

so you should consider using  `Dictionary` over `Hash-Table`