# Serialize an object with HashTable property and store in CouchBase

Tags: c#, couchbase

Our team has chosen [Couchbase](http://developer.couchbase.com/) as the cache for our application. What we store in this cache are objects look like this

```
public class CatalogEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // this property gives us trouble
    public Hashtable Attributes { get; set;}
}
```

In our code, after retrieve an object from the CouchBase cache, I found that properties of primary types(`Id` and `Name`) are properly deserialized, but the `Attributes` of `Hashtable` type is not deserialized and stay as JSON. For example, if I have something like

```
var entity = new CatalogEntity();
entity.Attributes["foo"] = new Foo();
```

The object from cache will have `Attributes["foo"]` property as JSON representation of the `Foo` class.

I am wondering how to have the `Hashtable` type properly serialize/deserialized? Should I serialize the object to binary and instead store binary stream in the CouchBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to use `Hashtable`? Can you use, for instance, a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead?

I think the reason for what you're seeing is Json.NET's best attempt to serialize a hashtable (see also this question on StackOverflow: [Serialize hashtable using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939880/serialize-hashtable-using-json-net)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am dealing with a legacy code base and switching to Dictionary is not so easy. 

But the linked question explained why the HashTable values are not de-serialized.  I end up manually de-serialize the values.