# How to sort/select top values from Hashtable?

Tags: c#, sorting, hashtable

I have a `Hashtable` with following content:

```
jak: 1
dsf: 1
usd: 1
idb: 1
bla: 3
sdd: 1
asd: 2
bsd: 1
```

I want to select top 10 pairs **by value**. In this example it would be like that:

```
bla: 3
asd: 2
```

etc. How do I do that?

Comment: If you're getting the top 10, why wouldn't the result have _all_ the values from the input?

Comment: @gunr2171 i have a lot more pairs, i just didnt wanna put them all in, besides i still need them sorted.

Comment: Why are you using a HashTable rather than a Dictionary? Because Dictionaries are generic you can easily do this with Linq.

Comment: @gunr2171 i will try that, thanks!

Comment: To make the example consistent with the question asked, you should probably edit the question like this: *"I want to select top **2** pairs..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap your code to using a dictionary, it'll look like:

```
var top10 = dict.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(10);
```

You can enumerate `top10`, which will be a sequence of KeyValuePair, and print their Key and Value properties

You can still do it with a hashtable, by the way (gunr's comment kinda implies that you can't use LINQ) and you can get LINQ to Cast all the entries to make them easier to work with:

```
hashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderByDescending(de => (int)de.Value).Take(10)
```

Comment: which is faster Hashtable or Dictionary?

Comment: I would't use Hashtable for new development. In either case this is going to be fairly slow, relatively speaking, because you're sorting potentially a lot of items to discard most. The alternatives are fairly intense though. If you have a specific performance requirement, state it as part of the inquiry. All in i think you'll have to get a very long list before it becomes an issue.. If your question is about raw performance of the dictionary vs hashtable as a data storage device maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast