# Performance of Hashtable vs Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, generics

Before you read: This question is about machine code and nanoseconds, because I do actually want to know it. Other criteria (like "Please use the generic way, because ...") are not what I'm asking for in this post.

### Scenario

I want to add a few (let's say 4) values to a "hashmap similar data structure" and afterwards, I want to query, whether there is a value for a given key.

The 2 options we consider: `Hashtable` and `Dictionary<T1,T2>`

### Goal

I want to minimize execution time (and optionally also IL size).

### Experiment

The same operations for `Dictionary` and `Hashtable`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Experiment {
    public void M() {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            dictionary.Add('a', 1);
            dictionary.Add('b', 5);
            dictionary.Add('c', 19);
            dictionary.Add('d', 92);
            var isInsideDictionary = dictionary.ContainsKey('e');
    }
    
    public void N(){
            var hashtable = new Hashtable();
            hashtable.Add('a', 1);
            hashtable.Add('b', 5);
            hashtable.Add('c', 19);
            hashtable.Add('d', 92);
            var isInsideTable = hashtable.ContainsKey('e');        
    }
}
```

### Resulting Asm (x64)

```
Experiment..ctor()
    L0000: ret

Experiment.M()
    L0000: push rsi
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x20
    L0005: mov rcx, 0x7ff94cd46758
    L000f: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L0014: mov rsi, rax
    L0017: mov rcx, rsi
    L001a: mov edx, 0x61
    L001f: mov r8d, 1
    L0025: mov r9d, 2
    L002b: mov rax, 0x7ff94cddf558
    L0035: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0037: mov rcx, rsi
    L003a: mov edx, 0x62
    L003f: mov r8d, 5
    L0045: mov r9d, 2
    L004b: mov rax, 0x7ff94cddf558
    L0055: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0057: mov rcx, rsi
    L005a: mov edx, 0x63
    L005f: mov r8d, 0x13
    L0065: mov r9d, 2
    L006b: mov rax, 0x7ff94cddf558
    L0075: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0077: mov rcx, rsi
    L007a: mov edx, 0x64
    L007f: mov r8d, 0x5c
    L0085: mov r9d, 2
    L008b: mov rax, 0x7ff94cddf558
    L0095: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0097: mov rcx, rsi
    L009a: mov edx, 0x65
    L009f: mov rax, 0x7ff94cddf528
    L00a9: call qword ptr [rax]
    L00ab: nop
    L00ac: add rsp, 0x20
    L00b0: pop rsi
    L00b1: ret

Experiment.N()
    L0000: push rdi
    L0001: push rsi
    L0002: push rbp
    L0003: push rbx
    L0004: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0008: vzeroupper
    L000b: mov rcx, 0x7ff940792378
    L0015: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L001a: mov rsi, rax
    L001d: vmovss xmm2, [0x7ff94da20278]
    L0025: mov rcx, rsi
    L0028: xor edx, edx
    L002a: mov rax, 0x7ff94072d888
    L0034: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0036: mov rdi, 0x7ff9404863a0
    L0040: mov rcx, rdi
    L0043: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L0048: mov rbx, rax
    L004b: mov word ptr [rbx+8], 0x61
    L0051: mov rbp, 0x7ff94045e8d0
    L005b: mov rcx, rbp
    L005e: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L0063: mov dword ptr [rax+8], 1
    L006a: mov r8, rax
    L006d: mov rdx, rbx
    L0070: mov rcx, rsi
    L0073: mov r9d, 1
    L0079: mov rax, 0x7ff94072dc60
    L0083: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0085: mov rcx, rdi
    L0088: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L008d: mov rbx, rax
    L0090: mov word ptr [rbx+8], 0x62
    L0096: mov rcx, rbp
    L0099: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L009e: mov dword ptr [rax+8], 5
    L00a5: mov r8, rax
    L00a8: mov rdx, rbx
    L00ab: mov rcx, rsi
    L00ae: mov r9d, 1
    L00b4: mov rax, 0x7ff94072dc60
    L00be: call qword ptr [rax]
    L00c0: mov rcx, rdi
    L00c3: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L00c8: mov rbx, rax
    L00cb: mov word ptr [rbx+8], 0x63
    L00d1: mov rcx, rbp
    L00d4: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L00d9: mov dword ptr [rax+8], 0x13
    L00e0: mov r8, rax
    L00e3: mov rdx, rbx
    L00e6: mov rcx, rsi
    L00e9: mov r9d, 1
    L00ef: mov rax, 0x7ff94072dc60
    L00f9: call qword ptr [rax]
    L00fb: mov rcx, rdi
    L00fe: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L0103: mov rbx, rax
    L0106: mov word ptr [rbx+8], 0x64
    L010c: mov rcx, rbp
    L010f: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L0114: mov dword ptr [rax+8], 0x5c
    L011b: mov r8, rax
    L011e: mov rdx, rbx
    L0121: mov rcx, rsi
    L0124: mov r9d, 1
    L012a: mov rax, 0x7ff94072dc60
    L0134: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0136: mov rcx, rdi
    L0139: call 0x00007ff9a0000b90
    L013e: mov word ptr [rax+8], 0x65
    L0144: mov rdx, rax
    L0147: mov rcx, rsi
    L014a: mov rax, 0x7ff940792458
    L0154: call qword ptr [rax]
    L0156: nop
    L0157: add rsp, 0x28
    L015b: pop rbx
    L015c: pop rbp
    L015d: pop rsi
    L015e: pop rdi
    L015f: ret
```

### Question

You can see that the number of ASM instructions is much lower when using `Dictionary<T1,T2>`. 37 vs 82...

Does that mean without any doubt, that you can say that doing what I have done is more performant with `Dictionary<T1,T2>` instead of `Hashtable`?

And is there any argument why you would not want to use `Dictionary<T1,T2>` instead of `Hashtable` considering performance? Does the generic approach result in more IL code, for example? Or does it behave differently when using reference types?

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-7.0#remarks

It says:

```We don't recommend that you use the Hashtable class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class.```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, see first sentence... I don't consider it for new code. It's more about replacing Hashtable with Dictionary in a very famous library where performance is crucial and whether it improves the performance or not or could even do the opposite. That's what I'm interested in, nothing else.

Comment: Not *"without any doubt"*, since execution time might not correspond 1:1 to the number of instructions executed (due to branch predictions etc.). However, since Hashtable exists only for backwards compatibility purposes and all optimization efforts of the last 15 years have been put into Dictionary instead of Hashtable, I would be *very* surprised if Hashtable were faster. If you want to know for sure, run a benchmark.

Comment: Why not just *measure* it yourself and compare the benchmarks? The number of instructions is rarely a good performance-indicator. Generelly I'd suggest to use the generic version, but not because its performance. But anyway `Hastable` and `Dictionary` aren't interchangable. In particular a `HashTable` just returns `null` if an element wasn't found, where a `Dictionary` throws an exception.

Comment: The major difference between them is at the very least that the integers will be boxed. What difference do you see if you use objects as the values? And the ASM for *your* code doesn't necessarily tell you the whole picture. When in doubt use BenchmarkDotNet for proper benchmarking.

Comment: I have used Benchmark.Net for a very similar scenario and it was like 100% vs 95% execution time (Dictionary was the faster one). I just wasn't sure whether that is enough of an argument. That's why I mentioned IL size and want to know whether there is more I did not think about..

Comment: @hardfork a HashTable requires wrapping all value types into objects, which has its own significant performance overhead, especially if you use a lot of structs, integers etc. All non-generic classes exist solely for backwards compatibility with pre-2005 code. All performance improvements go to the "new" types, including runtime vectorization of the actual code operations.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to convince the maintainers of a library to replace (or let you replace) `HashTable` with `Dictionary` in their code. I bet performance won't be their main concern here, but rather the breaking changes this might introduce. I think it's safe to say `Dictionary` will always be faster than `HashTable`. But is the performance increase significant enough to risk the change? You should a) do a benchmark tailored specifically to how the library uses `HashTable` and b) check what those breaking changes might be and how to avoid them.

Comment: Related: [.NET Hashtable vs Dictionary - Can the Dictionary be as fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft claims that, for value types, the performance of `Dictionary` is better than that of `Hashtable`:

> A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` of a specific type (other than `Object`) provides better performance than a `Hashtable` for value types. This is because the elements of `Hashtable` are of type `Object`; therefore, boxing and unboxing typically occur when you store or retrieve a value type.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/hashtable-and-dictionary-collection-types

---

> And is there any argument why you would not want to use `Dictionary<T1,T2>` instead of `Hashtable` considering performance?

In a single-threaded scenario: No. `Hashtable`'s only purpose is backwards-compatibility.

In a multi-threaded scenario, note that `Hashtable` is thread-safe for multiple readers and a single writer, which `Dictionary<T1, T2>` is not. You'd need to `lock` access to the dictionary (which has its own performance cost) or use `ConcurrentDictionary<T1, T2>`, which provides thread-safety for multiple readers and multiple writers.

Comment: In addition to the in-class cost savings that come from the elimination of boxing when either or both of `TKey` and `TValue` are value types, you also get a reduction in garbage generation when you get rid of boxing (if you are caring about nanoseconds).  In a garbage collected environment, you should always be cognizant of the cost of the GC (which necessarily comes later in your processing).

Answer (score 4):

> Does that mean without any doubt, that you can say that doing what I have done is more performant with Dictionary<T1,T2> instead of Hashtable?

Performance will likely be dominated by the actual code inside the dictionary or Hashtable. I would be very reluctant to make any guesses about performance from the size of assembly code alone. Some optimizations might increase the code size while still decreasing runtime.

I would *expect* `Dictionary<TKey, T>` to be faster, partly because it is generic and should allow for better optimizations, but also because it is newer and much more commonly used, so should have received more attention when it comes to optimizations.

But it you really want to know what is faster, [write a benchmark](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Ideally using [Benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). That should be much more reliable than guesses from random people on the internet.

Also note that `Dictionary<TKey, T>` is a general purpose collection, so need to make a careful balance between many different use cases. If you know the specific way your dictionary will be used and need every last cycle of performance, you could likely write your own that optimizes only for that specific use case.