# Caching in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I wanted to ask you what is the best approach to implement a cache in C#? Is there a possibility by using given .NET classes or something like that? Perhaps something like a dictionary that will remove some entries, if it gets too large, but where whose entries won't be removed by the garbage collector?

Comment: It depends *heavily* on the application. What are you using it for?

Comment: not in an asp.net manner but I don't know exactly yet I will post the requirements when I got them but thanks for your first answer :)

Comment: [Robust .NET Caching](http://www.codeducky.org/robust-net-caching/) covers common pitfalls of caching and provides a library that helps developers avoid some of the common pitfalls.  The post specifically explains how you can use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) safely.

Comment: This article worth a read : http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2010/08/30/Four-Methods-Of-Simple-Caching-In-NET.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, you could use the `Cache` class (`System.Web.Caching`).

Here is a good helper class: [c-cache-helper-class](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/)

If you mean caching in a windows form app, it depends on what you're trying to do, and where you're trying to cache the data.

We've implemented a cache behind a Webservice for certain methods
(using the `System.Web.Caching` object.).

However, you might also want to look at the Caching Application Block. ([See here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339057.aspx) that is part of the Enterprise Library for .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: I suggested an option for asp.net as well as an approach for when you're not. (Caching Application Block).

Comment: Does not matter if it is asp.net or not. You can reference System.Web in a desktop application and use System.Web.Cache through HttpRuntime.Cache property.

Comment: @RicardoNolde but it depends on which .net profile he links against. If he's using the default for a windows app (Client Profile), the System.Web namespace is not available.

Comment: [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) is available for those not using ASP.NET, in later versions of .NET.

Comment: Link is dead, [here's a cached version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216151931/johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/)

Answer (score 30):

If you are using .NET 4 or superior, you can use [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8.1) class.

Answer (score 5):

[MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the framework is a good place to start, but you might also like to consider the open source library [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache) because it has a simpler API than memory cache and has built in locking as well as some other developer friendly features. It is also available on nuget.

To give you an example:

```
// Create our cache service using the defaults (Dependency injection ready).
// Uses MemoryCache.Default as default so cache is shared between instances
IAppCache cache = new CachingService();

// Declare (but don't execute) a func/delegate whose result we want to cache
Func<ComplexObjects> complexObjectFactory = () => methodThatTakesTimeOrResources();

// Get our ComplexObjects from the cache, or build them in the factory func 
// and cache the results for next time under the given key
ComplexObject cachedResults = cache.GetOrAdd("uniqueKey", complexObjectFactory);
```

I recently wrote this article about [getting started with caching in dot net](https://alastaircrabtree.com/the-easy-way-to-add-caching-to-net-application-and-make-it-faster-is-called-lazycache/) that you may find useful.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of LazyCache)

Comment: A simpler API than MemoryCache? I find that hard to believe as it is arguably the easiest API Microsoft has to offer. I'm also trying to figure out the exact reason why you built a whole new caching API? It looks decent and all but why did you do all the effort for something that has been around and stable for ages.

Comment: It's not a massive change to memory cache, but handles the concurrency problem and reduces duplication with one line cashable delegates. Having written the same rough code several times it saves time for me having a library, and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

The cache classes supplied with .NET are handy, but have a major problem - they can not store much data (tens of millions+) of objects for a long time without killing your GC. They work great if you cache a few thousand objects, but the moment you move into millions and keep them around until they propagate into GEN2 - the GC pauses would eventually start to be noticeable when you system comes to low memory threshold and GC needs to sweep all gens.

The practicality is this - if you need to store a few hundred thousand instances - use MS cache. Does not matter if your objects are 2-field or 25 field - its about the number of references.

On the other hand there are cases when large RAMs, which are common these days, need to be utilized, i.e. 64 GB.
For that we have created a 100% managed memory manager and cache that sits on top of it.

Our solution can easily store 300,000,000 object in-memory in-process without taxing GC at all - this is because we store data in large (250 mb) byte[] segments.

Here is the code: [NFX Pile](https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/tree/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile)  (Apache 2.0)

And video:
 [NFX Pile Cache - Youtube](https://youtu.be/Dz_7hukyejQ)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ObjectCache.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx

Answer (score 2):

#### For Local Stores

- [.NET MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [NCache Express](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)
- [AppFabric Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx)
- ...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, the default choice using the .NET Framework is [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8) and the various related implementations in Microsoft NuGet packages (e.g. [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache)). All of these caches bound size in terms of memory used, and attempt to estimate memory used by tracking how total physical memory is increasing relative to the number of cached objects. A background thread then periodically 'trims' entries.

MemoryCache etc. share some limitations:

1. Keys are strings, so if the key type is not natively string, you will be forced to constantly allocate strings on the heap. This can really add up in a server application when items are 'hot'.
2. Has poor 'scan resistance' - e.g. if some automated process is rapidly looping through all the items in that exist, the cache size can grow too fast for the background thread to keep up. This can result in memory pressure, page faults, induced GC or when running under IIS, recycling the process due to exceeding the private bytes limit.
3. Does not scale well with concurrent writes.
4. Contains perf counters that cannot be disabled (which incur overhead).

Your workload will determine the degree to which these things are problematic. An alternative approach to caching is to bound the number of objects in the cache (rather than estimating memory used). A [cache replacement policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) then determines which object to discard when the cache is full.

Below is the source code for a simple cache with least recently used eviction policy:

```
public sealed class ClassicLru<K, V>
{
    private readonly int capacity;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<K, LinkedListNode<LruItem>> dictionary;
    private readonly LinkedList<LruItem> linkedList = new LinkedList<LruItem>();

    private long requestHitCount;
    private long requestTotalCount;

    public ClassicLru(int capacity)
        : this(Defaults.ConcurrencyLevel, capacity, EqualityComparer<K>.Default)
    { 
    }

    public ClassicLru(int concurrencyLevel, int capacity, IEqualityComparer<K> comparer)
    {
        if (capacity < 3)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Capacity must be greater than or equal to 3.");
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));
        }

        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<K, LinkedListNode<LruItem>>(concurrencyLevel, this.capacity + 1, comparer);
    }

    public int Count => this.linkedList.Count;

    public double HitRatio => (double)requestHitCount / (double)requestTotalCount;

    ///<inheritdoc/>
    public bool TryGet(K key, out V value)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref requestTotalCount);

        LinkedListNode<LruItem> node;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out node))
        {
            LockAndMoveToEnd(node);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref requestHitCount);
            value = node.Value.Value;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(V);
        return false;
    }

    public V GetOrAdd(K key, Func<K, V> valueFactory)
    {
        if (this.TryGet(key, out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        var node = new LinkedListNode<LruItem>(new LruItem(key, valueFactory(key)));

        if (this.dictionary.TryAdd(key, node))
        {
            LinkedListNode<LruItem> first = null;

            lock (this.linkedList)
            {
                if (linkedList.Count >= capacity)
                {
                    first = linkedList.First;
                    linkedList.RemoveFirst();
                }

                linkedList.AddLast(node);
            }

            // Remove from the dictionary outside the lock. This means that the dictionary at this moment
            // contains an item that is not in the linked list. If another thread fetches this item, 
            // LockAndMoveToEnd will ignore it, since it is detached. This means we potentially 'lose' an 
            // item just as it was about to move to the back of the LRU list and be preserved. The next request
            // for the same key will be a miss. Dictionary and list are eventually consistent.
            // However, all operations inside the lock are extremely fast, so contention is minimized.
            if (first != null)
            {
                dictionary.TryRemove(first.Value.Key, out var removed);

                if (removed.Value.Value is IDisposable d)
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return node.Value.Value;
        }

        return this.GetOrAdd(key, valueFactory);
    }

    public bool TryRemove(K key)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryRemove(key, out var node))
        {
            // If the node has already been removed from the list, ignore.
            // E.g. thread A reads x from the dictionary. Thread B adds a new item, removes x from 
            // the List & Dictionary. Now thread A will try to move x to the end of the list.
            if (node.List != null)
            {
                lock (this.linkedList)
                {
                    if (node.List != null)
                    {
                        linkedList.Remove(node);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (node.Value.Value is IDisposable d)
            {
                d.Dispose();
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Thead A reads x from the dictionary. Thread B adds a new item. Thread A moves x to the end. Thread B now removes the new first Node (removal is atomic on both data structures).
    private void LockAndMoveToEnd(LinkedListNode<LruItem> node)
    {
        // If the node has already been removed from the list, ignore.
        // E.g. thread A reads x from the dictionary. Thread B adds a new item, removes x from 
        // the List & Dictionary. Now thread A will try to move x to the end of the list.
        if (node.List == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (this.linkedList)
        {
            if (node.List == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            linkedList.Remove(node);
            linkedList.AddLast(node);
        }
    }

    private class LruItem
    {
        public LruItem(K k, V v)
        {
            Key = k;
            Value = v;
        }

        public K Key { get; }

        public V Value { get; }
    }
}
```

This is just to illustrate a thread safe cache - it probably has bugs and can be a bottleneck under heavy concurrent workloads (e.g. in a web server).

A thoroughly tested, production ready, scalable concurrent implementation is a bit beyond a stack overflow post. To solve this in my projects, I implemented a thread safe pseudo LRU (think concurrent dictionary, but with constrained size). Performance is very close to a raw ConcurrentDictionary, ~10x faster than MemoryCache, ~10x better concurrent throughput than ClassicLru above, and better hit rate. A detailed performance analysis provided in the github link below.

Usage looks like this:

```
int capacity = 666;
var lru = new ConcurrentLru<int, SomeItem>(capacity);

var value = lru.GetOrAdd(1, (k) => new SomeItem(k));
```

GitHub: https://github.com/bitfaster/BitFaster.Caching

```
Install-Package BitFaster.Caching
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarification. C# is a language not a framework. You have to specify which framework you want to implement the caching. If we consider that you want to implement it in ASP.NET it is still depends completely on what you want from Cache. You can decide between in-process cache (which will keep the data inside the heap of your application) and out-of-process cache (in this case you can store the data in other memory than the heap like Amazon Elastic cache server). And there is also another decision to make which is between client caching or serve side caching. Usually in solution you have to develop different solution for caching different data. Because base on four factors (accessibility, persistency, size, cost) you have to make decision which solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this some time ago and it seems to work well. It allows you to differentiate different cache stores by using different Types: `ApplicationCaching<MyCacheType1>, ApplicationCaching<MyCacheType2>...`.

You can decide to allow some stores to persist after execution and others to expire.

You will need a reference to the `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer (or use an alternative one) and of course all objects or values types to be cached must be serializable.

Use `MaxItemCount` to set a limit to the number of items in any one store.

A separate Zipper class (see code below) uses `System.IO.Compression`. This minimises the size of the store and helps speed up loading times.

```
public static class ApplicationCaching<K> 
{
        //====================================================================================================================
        public static event EventHandler InitialAccess = (s, e) => { };
        //=============================================================================================
        static Dictionary<string, byte[]> _StoredValues;
        static Dictionary<string, DateTime> _ExpirationTimes = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        //=============================================================================================
        public static int MaxItemCount { get; set; } = 0;
        private static void OnInitialAccess()
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            _StoredValues = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            InitialAccess?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        public static void AddToCache<T>(string key, T value, DateTime expirationTime)
        {
            try
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (_StoredValues is null) OnInitialAccess();
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                string strValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                byte[] zippedValue = Zipper.Zip(strValue);
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                _StoredValues.Remove(key);
                _StoredValues.Add(key, zippedValue);
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                _ExpirationTimes.Remove(key);
                _ExpirationTimes.Add(key, expirationTime);
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
        //=============================================================================================
        public static T GetFromCache<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default)
        {
            try
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (_StoredValues is null) OnInitialAccess();
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (_StoredValues.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    if (_ExpirationTimes[key] <= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        _StoredValues.Remove(key);
                        _ExpirationTimes.Remove(key);
                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        return defaultValue;
                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    }
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    byte[] zippedValue = _StoredValues[key];
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    string strValue = Zipper.Unzip(zippedValue);
                    T value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(strValue);
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    return value;
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                }
                else
                {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        //=============================================================================================
        public static string ConvertCacheToString()
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (_StoredValues is null || _ExpirationTimes is null) return "";
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            List<string> storage = new List<string>();
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string strStoredObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_StoredValues);
            string strExpirationTimes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ExpirationTimes);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            storage.AddRange(new string[] { strStoredObject, strExpirationTimes});
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string strStorage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storage);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            return strStorage;
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        //=============================================================================================
        public static void InializeCacheFromString(string strCache)
        {
            try
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                List<string> storage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(strCache);
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (storage != null && storage.Count == 2)
                {
                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    _StoredValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, byte[]>>(storage.First());
                    _ExpirationTimes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DateTime>>(storage.Last());
                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    if (_ExpirationTimes != null && _StoredValues != null)
                    {
                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        for (int i = 0; i < _ExpirationTimes.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string key = _ExpirationTimes.ElementAt(i).Key;
                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            if (_ExpirationTimes[key] < DateTime.Now)
                            {
                                ClearItem(key);
                            }
                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        if (MaxItemCount > 0 && _StoredValues.Count > MaxItemCount)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> countedOutItems = _ExpirationTimes.OrderByDescending(o => o.Value).Skip(MaxItemCount);
                            for (int i = 0; i < countedOutItems.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                ClearItem(countedOutItems.ElementAt(i).Key);
                            }
                        }
                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        return;
                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    }
                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                }
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                _StoredValues = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                _ExpirationTimes = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        //=============================================================================================
        public static void ClearItem(string key)
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (_StoredValues.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _StoredValues.Remove(key);
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (_ExpirationTimes.ContainsKey(key))
                _ExpirationTimes.Remove(key);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        //=============================================================================================
    }
```

You can easily start using the cache on the fly with something like...

```
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string key = "MyUniqueKeyForThisItem";
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            MyType obj = ApplicationCaching<MyCacheType>.GetFromCache<MyType>(key);
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (obj == default)
            {
                obj = new MyType(...);
                ApplicationCaching<MyCacheType>.AddToCache(key, obj, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));
            }
```

Note the actual types stored in the cache can be the same or different from the cache type. The cache type is ONLY used to differentiate different cache stores.

You can then decide to allow the cache to persist after execution terminates using `Default Settings`

```
string bulkCache = ApplicationCaching<MyType>.ConvertCacheToString();
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (bulkCache != "")
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.*MyType*DataCachingStore = bulkCache;
                }
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                try
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                catch (IsolatedStorageException)
                {
                    //handle Isolated Storage exceptions here
                }
```

Handle the InitialAccess Event to reinitialize the cache when you restart the app

```
private static void ApplicationCaching_InitialAccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string storedCache = Properties.Settings.Default.*MyType*DataCachingStore;
            ApplicationCaching<MyCacheType>.InializeCacheFromString(storedCache);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
```

Finally here is the Zipper class...

```
public class Zipper
    {
        public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

            int cnt;

            while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Zip(string str)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

            using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    CopyTo(msi, gs);
                }
                return mso.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
        {
            using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    CopyTo(gs, mso);
                }
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to Cache something in ASP.Net then I would look at the Cache class. For example

```
Hashtable menuTable = new Hashtable(); 
menuTable.add("Home","default.aspx"); 
Cache["menu"] = menuTable;
```

Then to retrieve it again

```
Hashtable menuTable = (Hashtable)Cache["menu"];
```

Answer (score -2):

**- Memory cache implementation for .Net core**

```cs
public class CachePocRepository : ICachedEmployeeRepository
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public CachePocRepository(
            IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository,
            IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetailsId(string employeeId)
        {
            _memoryCache.TryGetValue(employeeId, out Employee employee);

            if (employee != null)
            {
                return employee;
            }

            employee = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeDetailsId(employeeId);
            
            _memoryCache.Set(employeeId,
                employee,
                new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                {
                    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                });

            return employee;

        }
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a Hashtable

it has very fast lookups, no key collisions and your data will not garbage collected

Comment: but what if the hashtables becomes too big?

Comment: The only thing which might happen is that you run out of memory. If this is not the case, the hashtable runs fine. Internally it fixes key collisions it might encounter so you won't notice it.

Comment: Hashtable is not a cache, it is a lookup (if used for this purpose). A Cache has expiry, scavenging, capacity management and sometimes transaction support, freezing and many other features. Look at Caching Application Block although it forces you to bring in the whole farm of other Application Blocks and is very configuration heavy.

Comment: Hashtable class is now effectively dead in .NET, use a Dictionary (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable)