# Find from a hashtable using the value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following hash table:

```
private Hashtable Sid2Pid = new Hashtable();

Sid2Pid.Add(1,10);
Sid2Pid.Add(2,20);
Sid2Pid.Add(3,20);
Sid2Pid.Add(4,30);
```

Now how to get the list of keys from the above hashtable that has a value of 20 using LinQ

Answer (score 4):

A `HashTable` is `IEnumerable` of `DictionaryEntry`, with a little casting this can be converted into something the LINQ operators can work on:

```
var res = from kv in myHash.Cast<DictionaryEntry>
          where (int)kv.Value = targetValue
          select (int)kv.Key;
```

NB. This will throw an exception if you pass different types.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary<int, int>` instead of a Hashtable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c) for why) then do the following:

```
var keys = Sid2Pid.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 20)
                  .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```