# Initialize dictionary at declaration using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, dictionary, initialization, language-comparisons

Given this powershell code:

```
$drivers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$drivers.Add("nitrous","vx")
$drivers.Add("directx","vd")
$drivers.Add("openGL","vo")
```

Is it possible to initialize this dictionary directly without having to call the Add method. Like .NET allows you to do?

Something like this?

```
$foo = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'{{"a","Alley"},{"b" "bat"}}
```

[not sure what type of syntax this would involve]

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No. The initialization syntax for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is C# syntax candy. Powershell has its own initializer syntax support for `System.Collections.HashTable` (`@{}`):

```
$drivers = @{"nitrous"="vx"; "directx"="vd"; "openGL"="vo"};
```

For [probably] nearly all cases it will work just as well as `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. If you really need `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` for some reason, you could make a function that takes a `HashTable` and iterates through the keys and values to add them to a new `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

---

The C# initializer syntax isn't exactly "direct" anyway. The compiler generates calls to `Add()` from it.

Comment: I don't really need dictionary. A .NET hash table will work just fine.

Comment: It's worth noting that [a HashTable and a Dictionary do have differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable), but that those differences will largely be considered not relevant for common PowerShell scripting.

Comment: Strong-type is a good use case for us to use strictly a dict. I'm attempting to convert a property that was a hashtable to a Dict for that reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
$d = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,Object]]::new()
#works now.
$d.Add('keyvalue',  @{x=1; y='abc'})

#Evaluate dictionary
$d
<# outputs
Key      Value 
---      ----- 
keyvalue {y, x}
#>

#evalueate contains key:
$d.Keys.Contains('keyvalue')
<# outputs
True
#>

# Evaluate the value using the key
$d['keyvalue']
<# outputs
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
y                              abc                                                                                                                                                            
x                              1                                                                                                                                                              
#>

#Evaluate the y property of the object
 $d['keyvalue'].y
<# outputs
abc
#>

# Evaluate the x property of the object
$d['keyvalue'].x
<# outputs
1
#>
```