# which one is more preferable : dictionary or hashtable

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am often confused with `dictionary` and `hashtable` and wish to compare them, considering performance cost ...

Which one is more cost efficient ??

Comment: As with many things, it depends on what you want to use them for.

Comment: Comparing a `Collection<T>` and a `Collection<K,V>` on performance?

Comment: "i often confused with dictionary and hashtable by comparing them by considering performance cost" Then don't compare them by performance cost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Dictionary is preferred over hashtable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well... You'd think that a Hashtable would be a `Collection<T>`, but it's not. HashMap and Hashtable are basically the same thing, with the only difference being that Hashtable is synchronized. (Edit: I am talking about the Java classes here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, neither is preferable IMHO.  These are collections which were added in Java 1.0 and improved collections where added in Java 1.2 more than ten years ago.

For performance I would suggest you use

```
Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<Key, Value>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary is generic. It's newer, more type safe, and avoids unnecessary boxing.
In general, you should use a Dictionary wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a good [run down for c#](http://www.phase9studios.com/post/2008/01/08/DictionaryVSHashTable.aspx), its a little old but I think its still applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is better for small collections and hashtable for large ones. If you are unsure of how many items you will have then you could use the HybridDictionary:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx

**In response to comments**
In the article that i linked to in my original post it says:

*"This class is recommended for cases where the number of elements in a dictionary is unknown. It takes advantage of the improved performance of a ListDictionary with small collections, and offers the flexibility of switching to a Hashtable which handles larger collections better than ListDictionary."*

So, the HybridDictionary switches between ListDictonary and Hashtable. The generic Dictionary is implemented as a hash table as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

*"..the Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) class is implemented as a hash table."*
Not sure, but I guess this means that the generic Dictionary isn't as efficient as the untyped ListDictionary version for small collections.

Comment: Please give some justification for your statements. There are implementation differences, but to-all-intents-and-purposes `Dictionary<K,V>` is a generic -- ie, type-safe, non-boxing -- version of `Hashtable`. These days you should probably avoid `Hashtable`, `HybridDictionary` and their non-generic ilk unless you have a really compelling reason to use them.

Comment: There's a limit below which scanning a list will beat a dictionary, but it's pretty small. The generic dictionary always has the advantage of involving fewer casts, which is particularly significant in the case of value types, and always reduces the risk of bugs (worth paying a few cycles CPU for any day), which would offset any advantage of the list approach.

Comment: Since this question was about performance, not type safety, I believe the question about saving a couple of CPU cycles is very much relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the .NET side only:

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is almost certainly the one to go for. Its being typed to the types you are using it with will bring some performance gains in some cases, but much more importantly it makes its use simpler, cleaner and free from certain possible errors that can occur with `HashTable`.

Answer (score 1):

In .net: Hashtable has only one redeeming feature: if the following does not apply, use a dictionary.

But! A Hashtable allows concurrent readers without locking. You only need to synchronise **writes**. This makes it ideal as a cache in a multi-threaded application. I have some timings based on 25M reads, assuming hits: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/oimg?key=0Akv6EOgOa_qSdDk5ZC1zdzZ2ZWM1aFR0YkJlVE9GdkE&oid=2&zx=sukl7m2wm6am - x-axis is size of collection (key count), y-axis is time in milliseconds.

(the "concurrent" timing is ConcurrentDictionary)

Comment: One thing I was wondering about recently, is whether Dictionary can be safely used with the same degree of locking if the key and value typse are those that can be written atomically (a scan suggests it can in this case, but I haven't sat down and examined it deeply to really answer). Conjecture about implementation-specific details aside, is that image part of a bigger examination? As I'm experimenting with other approaches to concurrent dictionaries, I'd be interested in any such doc if it was public.

Comment: @Jon afaik it isn't just atomicity - I suspect it would just corrupt.

Comment: At a quick scan I think not, as long as writes where atomic and there was only one resize operation in effect at a time (which would require there be only one write at a time), I *think* it should be okay. Not that I'd use such a coincidental feature even if I did verify it was the case, I've just been looking of late at the details of what does cause corruption when it's caused. So are those timings part of something you can share?

Comment: @Jon I didn't save them particularly - ill see if I have the project still. Re testing it - spin up a mass of threads all editing should at least give incidental validation (neither formal nor robust, of course)

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing this and across different profiles (growing, shrinking, mutating in place, churning keys but keeping nearly-steady size, etc.) But it's always good to copy someone else's benchmark approaches, as it defeats the subconscious tendency to lean to those you're own approach will do well at.