# Strongly Typed Multidimensional Array/Collection

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, strongly-typed-dataset

I want to create a strongly typed multidimensional array or collection containing the following values from a database:

- FileName (As String)
- FileSize (As Integer)

Requirements:

- Accessible via index (e.g. Arr(i)(j), Arr.Row(i), etc)
- Efficient (i.e. fast & not resource intensive)
- Easily manipulated, added to, appended, etc.
- .NET 3.5 compatible

---

Thanks for the great answers everyone. Here's what I went with... :)

```vb
Structure FileRecord
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Size As Integer

    Sub New(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileSize As Integer)
        Me.Name = FileName
        Me.Size = FileSize
    End Sub
    Sub New(ByVal Files() As FileRecord)
        For Each f As FileRecord In Files
            Dim fr As New FileRecord(f.Name, f.Size)
        Next
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Comment: In light of comments I opted to go with a `Structure` instead of a class, as it has a cleaner implementation than a `Class` with `Properties`. I'll post a sample below my original question.

Comment: [Dont use a mutable structure!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441309)

Comment: O.o Excellent piece of knowledge. You learn something everyday. Thanks @MarkJ! :)
Now are Structures mutable by definition? Or can they be made immutable? I'm a big fan of clean code. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a multidimensional array containing two separate types.

Instead, you'd typically make a single dimensional array (or `List(Of T)`) containing a custom class with your data.

In your case, you might want something like:

```
Public Class FileRecord
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Size as Integer
End Class
```

Then, make a `List(Of FileRecord)` to hold your data.  You'd then be able to access this as:

```
Dim nameAtIndex = theList(i).Name
Dim sizeAtIndex = theList(i).Size
```

Comment: O.o now that's a scrumptious answer. Worked until 3am, so a little brain fried atm, thanks! ;)

Comment: Hello @ReedCopsey, would you mind terribly if I gave the rep to Kapil as he has less rep and his answer was quite similar and helpful?

Comment: @Chiramisu Accept whichever answer you prefer ;)  It's fine with me - in general, pick the answer you feel helped you the most or is best, regardless of reputation (which really doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things)

Comment: You're right, though I would like enough rep to add tags :P... I did like your example on accessing the items though, which was helpful. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @Chiramisu I'm sure it'll come quick - just keep asking, and more importantly, answering questions ;)  (BTW - I voted Kapil's answer up, too - and would be find if you pick his)

Answer (score 3):

You can use generic list collection:

```
Public Class MyItem   
  Public Property  FileName As String
  Public Property  FileSize As Integer   
End Class
```

Now you can have a list:

```
Dim MyItems AS List(Of MyItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that while it's not strongly-typed, the [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aahzb21x) class performs the best for storing and retrieving large amounts of data.  If FileName is unique, that would be your key.  Furthermore, you could wrap a hashtable in another class, and provide strongly-typed methods for adding and retrieving.

According to an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c) SO post, [Dictionary(of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) provides a generic implementation of a hashtable.  Might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it SUPER SIMPLE. I really dislike when programmers make things more complicated than they need to be.

```
Dim Multi_Dimensional_Array As Object(,) = _
        {{"Item 1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, 
         {"Item 2", "6", "7", "8", 9"", "No More Items"}}
```

You can change it from "Object" to "String" if you choose.