# C# compare 2 files contents for matches

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to find a way to compare some text in 2 files and if a match is found then run a process.

Here are examples of the files;

**'File A'** = Automated list of text with this format;

```
example1
ex2
289 Example
fht_nkka
```

**'File B'** = File names from a directory search;

```
example1
test2
test4785
```

Using my 2 example files, I want to search them both and find matches.

So 'File A' above contains 'example1' and 'example1' is in 'File B'. What I want to be able to do is create 'string[] match based on all matches. Is there an easy way of doing this?

NOTE: these files do not always have the same line data or amount of lines in.

Comment: UPDATE - I can also change the layout of 'File A' if needed but the line items will be the same either way

Comment: have you tried anything? any code sample?

Comment: I am a beginner with C# so not tried anything yet as I am stuck as to how to do it. I have other searches being run elsewhere but they are looking for static search criteria, this dynamic 'search and run' process has stumped me :S

Comment: If this project grows beyond the capabilities of your homegrown solution, you may want to look into [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to sort this out, here is what I have done;

```
var fileAcontents = File.ReadAllLines(fileA);
var fileBcontents = File.ReadAllLines(fileB);

HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(fileAcontents);
foreach (string i in fileBList)
{
    if (hashSet.Contains(i))
    {
        // <- DO SOMETHING :)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a universal solution if you want to compare 2 files like a diff tool. It will not work if `fileA` has duplicate lines. `HashSet` cannot contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` on each of the two files to create two string arrays.
2. Create a sorted version of array containing filenames to improve search performance. You can use LINQ for this purpose.
3. Given that your first file has a fixed layout, your required filename should always be at Line No. 4 for each record, so you can use a `for` loop on your second array with fixed increment to read the required filename.
4. Use `Array.BinarySearch()` to quickly locate whether that required filename exists in the list of files (the other array that is).

Here is a rough sketch of the code:

```
string[] AllRecs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FIRST_FILE_PATH);
string[] AllFileNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SECOND_FILE_PATH);
Array.Sort(AllFileNames);

for (int i = 3; i < AllRecs.Length; i += 8) 
{
    if (Array.BinarySearch(AllFileNames, AllRecs(i) + ".exe") >= 0)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AllRecs(i) + ".exe");

}
```

Comment: considering he is begginer with C# this approach is rather complex

Comment: Ya, I kind of agree, but then he has to start it from somewhere, so why not today. :)

Comment: Sorted array is not the most efficient. HashSet is, plus is simpler. Then a simple contains would yield a result in approx constant time vs n squared time.

Comment: @dotNET why the i += 8 ?

Comment: I take it the i += 8 is for the end of the file. The file is dynamic and may not only be 8 lines long. It gets over written each time so the beginning would always be 3 lines. Again, these 3 lines can be removed if it makes the process easier

Comment: @Aron: +1 for HashSet. N squared time is a bit of exaggeration though. I'm using BinarySearch on sorted array, so the average time would be near Log(N).
For the rest of us, the structure of your *File A* appears to have 8 lines of text per record, if I understand correctly. Starting with Line[3] (i.e. 4th line) would give you the file name from the first record. Adding 8 in the next iteration will move the index to the file name line of the 2nd record and so on.

Comment: the file gets recreated at each run. it may not always be 8 lines long. i can remove the first 3 lines from the file as it is something the code creates earlier. that way it will just be a list of text

Answer (score 0):

```
//Keep in a list of strings with FileA contents 

List<string> linesOfFileA = new List<string>();
string line ;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFileA)) 
{
    //read each line of fileA
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
        linesOfFileA.Add(line) ;
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
//Now read the contents of FileB

string fileWithoutExtension ;
int posOfExtension ;

using (StreamReader srB = new StreamReader(pathToFileB)) 
{
    //read each line of fileB
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
        posOfExtension = line.LastIndexOf(".");

        if(posOfExtension < 0)
        {
            fileWithoutExtension = line ;
        }               
        else
        {
            fileWithoutExtension = line.Substring(0,posOfExtension) ;
        }

        //Check to see if the FileA contains file but without Extension
        if(linesOfFileA.Contains(fileWithoutExtension))
        {
            //Store into another list / or execute here
        }
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In the first part of the code you skip the number of lines that you need, but because of the current shown format they will not affect your comparison

Comment: ok, so I have removed the extensions from fileB so now the files are just lines of data. I have created the first list based on fileA. What would be the easiest way to check for 'matches' and write to string[] match = 'matches'?

Answer (score -1):

Fill a dictionary object with File A contents then loop through File B contents querying File A dictionary object. Reason for dictionary object is its speed if you have a large array of data.

```
Dictionary<int, string> FileA = new Dictionary<int, string>();
string sFileAList = dataFileA;
```

Loop through File A contents and add to Dict where i is a counter.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string s in sFileAList.split('\n')) {
    count++;
    if (count > 3) FileA.Add(i, s);
}
```

Then compare while looping through File B contents.

```
foreach (string s in dataFileB.split('\n')) {
    if (FileA.ContainsValue(s)) {
        // Run exe
    }
}
```

Comment: FileB is what type of object ?

Comment: -1 Dictionary for speed? How does your index help with speed?

Comment: I doesn't. I've just added the index to fill the that part of the object. The reason is cause it's a hash table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable

Comment: Yeah...The hash is on the int...What you want is `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Oh, it's on the key. Got mixed up. So if I swapped it wrong, that would be ok?