# how to use hashtable in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, hashtable, icollection

I am trying to use hash table in linq to fetch the key whose value is `ABC`.
What I have done so far:

```
Hashtable h=new Hashtable ();
h.Add(1 , "ABC");
h.Add(2 , "AgC");
h.Add(3 , "ABC");
h.Add(4 , "AhC");
```

Expected output: **1, 3** *(keys having value "ABC")*

```
ICollection c= h.Keys;

var posi= from a in c
          where h[a]="ABC"
          select a;
```

But the above query is not working and giving compile time error.

The error is:

> could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.ICollection'.

What I am doing wrong? I am new to C#. How to use Hashtable in LINQ?

Comment: I would recommend using a `Dictionary`. [More info on `Hashtable` vs `Dictionary` here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use non-generic `HashTable` to start with. Use generic `Dictionary<int, string>` instead:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1 , "ABC");
d.Add(2 , "AgC");
d.Add(3 , "ABC");
d.Add(4 , "AhC");

var posi = from a in d
           where a.Value == "ABC"
           select a.Key;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir but how can we implement the same using Hashtable? Thanks in advance

Comment: And also if I am using group by a.Value I am getting error can't convert to lambda expression. Why?

Comment: How could a possibly know without you showing how query with `group by` looks like?

Comment: posi = from a in d
           Group by a.Value
           select a.Key;

Comment: You should start with LINQ tutorials. You have to specify not only the key, but also what values you want to group. Should be `group a by a.Value into g`

Comment: @user2623213 A Dictionary IS a Hashtable. It's just a generic version.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of a Hashtable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c) for why) then do the following:

```
var dist = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dist.Add(1 , "ABC");
dist.Add(2 , "AgC");
dist.Add(3 , "ABC");
dist.Add(4 , "AhC");

var keys = dist.Where(d=> d.Value == "ABC").Select(d=> d.Key);
```

But If you want Hastable, Then please take a look this link

[link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_hashtable.htm)

[link 2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable)

But My opinion is, Please use `Dictionary` .

> Because `Dictionary`  is a generic collections, And It's are a lot faster as there's no boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to use that `HashTable` instead of the `Dictionary` you can do the following:

```
var posi = from a in c.Cast<int>()
           where h[a] == "ABC"
           select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this to get position:

```
int indexOf ( object s, Hashtable h )
{
    foreach ( DictionaryEntry e in h )
        if ( e.Value.Equals(s) )
            return (int)e.Key;
    return -1;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var posi = indexOf("ABC", yourHashTable);
```

but it is true that using `Dictionary` would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The question is specifically for Hashtables, why do people replays "use dictionary instead" ? I would mark these replies all as out of topic.