# UnityEngine.WWW.WWW(string, byte[], System.Collections.Hashtable)' is obsolete

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an obsolete warning after updating to Unity 4.5 :

> Warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.WWW.WWW(string, byte[], System.Collections.Hashtable)' is obsolete:`This overload is deprecated. Use the one with Dictionary argument.' (CS0618) (Assembly-CSharp)

The codes are as follow:

```
public class Request {
    public string url;
    public NetworkDelegate del;
    public WWWForm form;
    public byte[] bytes;
    public Hashtable header;

    // Constructors
    public Request(string url, NetworkDelegate del) {
        this.url = url;
        this.del = del;
    }

    public Request(string url, NetworkDelegate del, WWWForm form) : this(url, del) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Request(string url, NetworkDelegate del, byte[] bytes) : this(url, del) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public Request(string url, NetworkDelegate del, byte[] bytes, Hashtable header) : this(url, del, bytes) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public WWW makeWWW() {
        if(header != null) {
            return new WWW(url, bytes, header); // problematic line
        }
        if(bytes != null) {
            return new WWW(url, bytes);
        }
        if(form != null) {
            return new WWW(url, form);
        }
        return new WWW(url);
    }
}
```

How should I change the line?

*The original codes can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/asus4/2490117).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WWW` constructor is not expecting an `Hashtable` anymore, but a `Dictionary` (its generic equivalent)

Do as the warning says : replace your `Hashtable header` member with a `Dictionary<K,V>` , K being the type of the Keys in the table, V the type of the values.

EDIT:

Also see [why is Dictionary preferred over hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable)

Comment: I replaced all `Hashtable` to `Dictionary<string, string>`. It works. Thanks.