# How to typecast System.String to BOO.lang.hash in Unityscript Unity3D?

Tags: json, hash, unity-game-engine, hashtable, unityscript

I found a tutorial for server implementation in a game on this link:

http://unity-tutorials.blogspot.in/

I implemented the code for my server sending in the following data on the Login Section to my Server:

```
{"email":"rudi@mrpatch.co", "pass": "mrpatch"}
```

This server is implementing JSON and is giving the below response :

```
Receive response: "{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"email\":\"rudi@mrpatch.co\",\"password\":\"mrpatch\",\"first_name\":\"Rudi\",\"last_name\":\"Ullon\",\"birth_date\":\"1981-03-20\",\"status\":\"1\"}]}"
```

There is a JSON parser script in this project, which returns System.string , this is being used by a parser in my other script LoginService.js 
But while I am trying to store this in a Boo.Lang.Hash (hashtable) it gives me error in following code:

```
var parsed : Boo.Lang.Hash = JSONParse.JSONParse(httpResponse.text);
```

This is the Error message I am getting:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
LoginService+$sendLoginData$6+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/StartMenu/LoginService.js:61)
```

I have tried saving it a Boo.Lang.Hash, as String etc. but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have json you can do in this way.

```
var parsed : Boo.Lang.Hash = JSONParse.JSONParse(your json );
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy...

You seem to have quite some conceptual issues with [type casting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp) and that's a far [too broad topic <sup>(joke link)</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_casting_%28typography%29). :P

The error message means you can't convert from `String` to that [`Hashtable`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Hashtable.html) through casting. You need a function to convert it for you or do it yourself.

The [`JSONParse`](https://github.com/tonioloewald/jsonparse) you mentioned can actually do it:

```
var jsonData : json = json.fromString(httpResponse.text);
```

At least now you have `jsonData.values` which can be easily converted to a Hashtable...

But keep in mind ["Hashtables" are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable) and even the Unity Player will warn you about it. [Read more](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use?).

Answer (score 0):

you must use the JsonPare.js from source code on the demo.https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0HipNssJJD-bEh0Wi1XeV9PSlE/edit