# Accessing a variable's name by using index of for loop

Tags: c#, variables, for-loop

Let's say I have 4 strings.

```
private string string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4;
```

Then let's say I have a for loop. How can I access the variable name by the index of the for loop? Here's an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    string_ + i = "Hello, world! " + i;
}
```

I understand that doing the above will not compile.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use dictionary instead

Comment: You can't do this. If you want to have a list of strings, then use the `List<string>` type, or a string array.

Comment: I'm reading MSDN right now. Is Dictionary like a hash map then? @prashanth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable

Comment: Thank you @prashanth. You've answered my question. How do I select it as the answer? And thank you for your input DavidG.

Comment: just upvote my comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're asking - at least directly.

You could start with simply putting the strings into an array and then work from the array.

```
string[] strings = new []
{
    string_1,
    string_2,
    string_3,
    string_4,
};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    strings[i] = "Hello, world! " + i;
}

Console.WriteLine(string_3); // != "Hello, world! 2"
Console.WriteLine(strings[2]); // == "Hello, world! 2"
```

But then the original `string_3` is unchanged, although its slot in the array is correct.

You can go one step further and do it this way:

```
Action<string>[] setStrings = new Action<string>[]
{
    t => string_1 = t,
    t => string_2 = t,
    t => string_3 = t,
    t => string_4 = t,
};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    setStrings[i]("Hello, world! " + i);
}

Console.WriteLine(string_3); // == "Hello, world! 2"
```

This works as originally intended - `string_3` does get updated. It is a little contrived though, but may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] hello = new string[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    hello[i] = "Hello, world! " + i;
}
```

If you want a variable-length list, use a type that implements `ICollection<string>`, for instance `Dictionary<string>`, `HashSet<string>` or `List<string>`.

Answer (score -1):

Put your strings into an array, then use the for loop to iterate through the array. As you iterate through the array call your command on the ith element of your array.

```
String[ ] array = ["a", "b","c"];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
// print array[i]
```