# Check duplicate key in Hashtable before adding a key

Tags: c#-4.0, overriding, hashtable

I have a Hashtable and I want to put **check whether the Hashtable has key or not before adding a key** in Hashtable. As adding a duplicate key in Hashtable throwing exception. 
Basically I want to override Hashtable's virtual 'Add' method and put a check in it. I dont know how can I override Add method.

Please help me to write override method.

Comment: Why do you still use a `HashTable`? Use a `Dictionary<Tkey, Tval>`. However, use [`ContainsKey `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Actually its a older code and can not replace it for now. Replacement require so much efforts.

Comment: In project on hundreds of place we are adding key in Hashtable. But now at many places it may add duplicate key. and at that time it throws exception. I want to avoid this exception and want to put only one common check to reduce efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [`ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another way is to use the [`Item` indexer-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.110).aspx) which adds new keys and updates existing.

```
var ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
ht["test"] = "foo"; // added
ht["test"] = "bah"; // updated
```

However, you should consider to replace your old and redundant `Hashtable` with a generic  `Dictionary<Tkey, Tval>`. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable)

Answer (score 0):

The Add method of the Hashtable class is overridable. So try this:

```
class MyHashTable : Hashtable
{
    public override void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
        catch
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```