# Modify Hashtable value of a specific key

Tags: c#

I need to increase the value of a specific key in a `Hashtable`, 
here is my code (I want to create the `Hashtable` during the function,
and I want the table to be like that - `<string><int>`):

```
public void getMssg(string ipSend, string mssg, Hashtable table)
{
    if (table.Contains(ipSend))
        table[ipSend]++;        //error
}
```

By the way, can I define a `Hashtable` like I wrote above?

Comment: You shouldn't use `HashTable`, ever.   Use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: consider going through: [why is Dictionary preferred over hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/301371/6400526)

Comment: Thank you both, Dictionary is realy better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getMssg(string ipSend, string mssg, Hashtable table)
{
    if (table.Contains(ipSend))
    {
        int value = (int)table[ipSend];
        table[ipSend] = value + 1;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, a Dictionary approach would be much better because it is type safe and eliminates the casting. Hashtables are not suitable for this kind of usage. Just an example:

```
public void getMssg(string ipSend, string mssg, Dictionary<string,int> table)
{
    if (table.ContainsKey(ipSend))
        table[ipSend] += 1;
    else
        table.Add(ipSend, 1);
}
```

I updated the above code following the advice of @mjwills: TryGetValue outperforms ContainsKey:

```
public void getMssg(string ipSend, string mssg, IDictionary<string, int> table)
{
    int result;

    if(!table.TryGetValue(ipSend, out result))
        result = 0;

    table[ipSend] = result + 1;
}
```

Comment: Typos everywhere.

Comment: I would suggest using `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead.

```
public void getMssg(string ipSend, IDictionary<string, int> table)
{
    int result;
    if(!table.TryGetValue(ipSend, out result))
        result = 0; // do something if the key is not found
    table[ipSend] = ++result;
}
```