# Should I dispose local class variables?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, idisposable

I have a legacy application where I am getting `OutOfMemory` exception time to time. I am trying to debug and fix the issue. One of the option I am thinking is to use the `Dispose()`  method. I know that any object implementing the `IDisposable` interface will let me call the `Dispose()` method on it but will it also help freeing up resources to set the class level variables to `null`? like `ArrayList` or `Hashtable`?

I did search on internet and found a few posts but got a bit confused whether to `null` objects or not.

**Code I am trying**

```
public class RepET : base_entitlement, IDisposable
{
    #region Public Member Variables
    public const int ENTITLEMENT_TYPE = 7;
    public string table = "acc_rep";
    public ArrayList country_list;
    public Hashtable data;
    public ArrayList survey_dates;
    public ArrayList city_list;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> cityData;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> reportCity_list;
    public RepET(string entId)
    {
        if (id != "0")
        {
            id = entId;
            // if we cant load the metadata then load the full records & build the metadata

            if (!LoadFromMetaDb(id, ENTITLEMENT_TYPE))
            {
                if (this.load_entitlements())
                {
                    serialize_to_metadb(this, ENTITLEMENT_TYPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public bool load_entitlements()
    {
        //  loads this entitlement from the metadata
        this.data = new Hashtable();
        this.survey_dates = new ArrayList();
        this.city_list = new ArrayList();
        //SqlQueries.ProcessingStarted(id);
        var sdates = SqlQueries.GetNewestSurveyByET(this.table, id, "acc_rep");

        if (sdates.Count == 0) return false;
        else
        {
            //delete ent 4 if already exist as its regenerated here
            check_EntFile_Created(id, Constants.ENTITLEMENT_TYPE_RP.ToString(), true);
            o_report_entitlements = new report_entitlements(id);

            reportCity_list = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            foreach (string sd in sdates)
            {
                ent_by_survey_date(sd.Trim(), true);
                this.survey_dates.Add(sd.Trim());
            }
            o_report_entitlements.serialize_to_metadb(o_report_entitlements, Constants.ENTITLEMENT_TYPE_RP);

            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool ent_by_survey_date(string survey_date, bool modify_report_entitlements = false)
    {

        //if (modify_report_entitlements) {
        //    ArrayList countryArray;
        //}

        var dt = SqlQueries.Ent_by_survey_date(table, id, survey_date, "acc");
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            country_list = new ArrayList();
            city_list = new ArrayList();

            Dictionary<string, ArrayList> countryCodes = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string current_city_code = row["city_code"].ToString().Trim();
                string current_report_type = row["report_type"].ToString().Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(current_city_code))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> currentCityReportList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    if (!reportCity_list.ContainsKey(survey_date))
                    {
                        reportCity_list[survey_date] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        reportCity_list[survey_date].Add(current_city_code, current_report_type);
                    }
                    else if (reportCity_list != null && reportCity_list.ContainsKey(survey_date) && !reportCity_list[survey_date].ContainsKey(current_city_code))
                    {
                        reportCity_list[survey_date].Add(current_city_code, current_report_type);
                    }

                    if (modify_report_entitlements)
                    {

                        string current_country_code = get_country_code_by_city(current_city_code);

                        if (!country_list.Contains(current_country_code))
                        {
                            country_list.Add(current_country_code);
                            foreach (var item in ((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)(o_report_entitlements.GetType())).DeclaredFields)
                            {
                                if (item.Name == "data")
                                {
                                    Hashtable tempObj = (Hashtable)item.GetValue(o_report_entitlements);
                                    if (tempObj != null)
                                    {
                                        countryCodes = (Dictionary<string, ArrayList>)tempObj[id];
                                        if (countryCodes != null && !countryCodes.ContainsKey(current_country_code))
                                            this.o_report_entitlements.add_to_array(current_country_code, "ACC", "", ref countryCodes);
                                        else if (countryCodes != null && countryCodes.ContainsKey(current_country_code) && !countryCodes[current_country_code].Contains("ACC"))
                                            this.o_report_entitlements.add_to_array(current_country_code, "ACC", "", ref countryCodes);
                                        else if (!countryCodes.ContainsKey(current_country_code))
                                            this.o_report_entitlements.add_to_array(current_country_code, "ACC", "", ref countryCodes);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (countryCodes == null)
                                            countryCodes = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
                                        this.o_report_entitlements.add_to_array(current_country_code, "ACC", "", ref countryCodes);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!city_list.Contains(current_city_code))
                    {
                        city_list.Add(current_city_code);
                    }
                    if (!currentCityReportList.ContainsKey(current_city_code))
                    {
                        currentCityReportList.Add(current_city_code, current_report_type);
                    }
                    if (!data.ContainsKey(survey_date))
                    {
                        data[survey_date] = new Hashtable();
                    }
                    switch ((((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])).GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
                    {
                        case true:
                            break;
                        case false:
                        default:
                            ((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            (((Dictionary<string, string>)((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code])["city_code"]) = current_city_code;
                            //(((Dictionary<string, string>)((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code])["city_code"])


                            //(((Dictionary<string, ArrayList>)((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code])["report_type"]) = new ArrayList();
                            (((Dictionary<string, string>)((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code])["report_type"]) = current_report_type;
                            //((Dictionary<string, string>)((Hashtable)this.data[survey_date])[current_city_code])["report_type"] = current_report_type;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public string get_country_code_by_city(string city_code)
    {

        load_city_list();
        string returnItem = null;
        foreach (var item in cityData)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> subItem = item.Value;
            if (subItem.ContainsKey(city_code))
            {
                returnItem += item.Key;
            }
        }
        return returnItem;
    }

    public bool load_city_list()
    {
        if (GlobalObjs.dtCityList.Rows.Count == 0)
            GlobalObjs.dtCityList = SqlQueries.LoadCityList();

        //var dt = SqlQueries.LoadCityList();
        if (GlobalObjs.dtCityList.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Dictionary<string, string> cityList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        cityData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        foreach (DataRow row in GlobalObjs.dtCityList.Rows)
        {
            string Country_Code = row["Country_Code"].ToString().Trim();
            string City_Code = row["City_Code"].ToString().Trim();
            string City_Name = row["Name"].ToString().Trim();

            if (!cityData.ContainsKey(Country_Code))
            {
                cityData.Add(Country_Code, new Dictionary<string, string>());
            }

            Dictionary<string, string> tempList = cityData[Country_Code];
            if (!tempList.ContainsKey(City_Code))
            {
                tempList.Add(City_Code, City_Name);
                //cityList.Add(City_Code, City_Name);
                cityData[Country_Code] = tempList;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }



    // Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
    bool disposed = false;

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            country_list = null;
            data = null;
            survey_dates = null;
            city_list = null;
            cityData = null;
            reportCity_list = null;
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

will this help with the memory exception?

Comment: no, setting internal class members won't help with OutOfMemoryErrors. GC is pretty smart to free memory occupied by `RepET` properties. The problem is that something holds references (like static event handlers) so you have to find the memory leak. You can use in-built VS memory profiler snapshots to check the difference between snapshots and try to find object are not being removed by GC. Do you dispose `RepET.connection` property BTW ?

Comment: Dispose has nothing to do with memory usage.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `ArrayList`, use `List<T>` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist#remarks)). I would also avoid `Hashtable` if possible (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c))

Comment: @Rohit post the *rest* of the code. Typically OOMs are caused by memory fragmentation caused by trying to insert eg 1M items into a list without specifying an initial capacity. The quick fix is to specify a capacity for the container. The *real* fix is to just *not* load all that data in the first place

Comment: @Rohit this means that the methods in the question's code probably aren't relevant. The *relevant* code is the code that creates and loads those container fields (they aren't variables). Specifying a capacity when creating the containers could fix the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the suggestion,  what do you mean by specifying capacity?

Comment: @Rohit I mean that you should post your code. When you create any container you can specify a capacity but *why are you loading so many items* in the first place? Whatever your code does, it doesn't have to store 1M items in memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have pasted the code. its a long code

Comment: You are using various DataTables and such. What is the size of them (number of rows, number of columns)?

Answer (score 4):

The only time setting fields to `null` will make a difference to garbage collection is if you're still somehow leaving the `RepET` instance reachable in some way, in which case the real solution is: make sure that the `RepET` instance is no longer reachable! Setting the fields to `null` is papering over the real problem.

It is appropriate to use `Dispose()` to cascade things like `connection` and `cmd`, but... another part of me thinks the better approach there would be to *not store them*, i.e. obtain the connection on-demand, and keep `cmd` entirely local to where it is used; something like:

```cs
using (var conn = SomeHelper.CreateConnection())
{
    // your "cmd" code in here, via "using" - or
    // perhaps via "Dapper" and let it worry about that
}
```

The real trick, though, is finding what is holding the instance, *if* that is the real problem. Hard to comment without context, but: events and static caches are good places to start looking.

Comment: I also though of updating the DB connection code to use `using` thanks for suggestion. I'll change it in code.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Microsoft documentation, the OutOfMemory exception is thrown when CLR can not allocate contiguous memory to perform an operation. In your case, since you are using Array-based data structures which may need contiguous memory allocation to a lot of data, hence you are getting the error.

-
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.8][1]

Instead of loading all the data at once into these array-based data structures, you may want to load as much less data as required for processing or try lazy loading

Comment: That is a reasonable *hypothesis* that warrants investigation; I would be hesitant to presume that it is the *explanation*; I've seen OOMs from far more subtle and nuanced things than simply oversized arrays. But yes: oversized arrays should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, @HansKeﬆing for the correction! updated the spellings.